# Average filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter

I'm trying to compute the average of every pixel with just the left and right neighbors but at the end of my processing I get only a white image, I can't find where my error. Here's my code

```
imageIn = imread('Prueba.jpg');
imageIn = rgb2gray(imageIn);
imageOut = zeros(size(imageIn));

ny = size(imageIn, 1);
nx = size(imageIn, 2);

imshow(imageIn);

u = [];
v = [];

tic

for i = 1:ny
    u = imageIn(i,:);
    v = zeros(1, ny);
    for k = 2:ny-1
        v(k) = (uint32(u(k-1))+uint32(u(k))+uint32(u(k+1)))/3;
    end
    %Special cases first and last pixel
    v(1) = (uint32(u(2))+uint32(u(1))+uint32(u(2)))/3;
    v(ny) = (uint32(u(ny-1))+uint32(u(ny))+uint32(u(ny-1)))/3;
    imageOut(i,:) = v;
end

toc
imshow(imageOut);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you handling the edge cases?  What if a pixel doesn't have a left or right neighbor?

Comment: When it does not have left neighbor i use twice the right pixel and viceversa. That's what the lines below the commen `special cases` do (or should do).

Comment: it has been a very long time I used matlab, but I think you might be using integer division, which will return an integer number, not a floating point number? If you omit the ; i believe it will output the var while running, so maybe output v everytime it is done processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the last line of your code to `imagesc(imageOut)` and you'll see that the image is not in fact white.

Your code is fine; the reason the image appears white using the `imshow()` function is because after applying your local average the range of pixel intensities is considerably smaller and the default scaling used by `imshow()` is insufficient to bring out the contrast of the image.

Read about the difference b/t `imshow()` and `imagesc()` and you'll see the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, actually I just found another way to do that, with `imageOut = mat2gray(imageOut)`. I will read the difference. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a 2nd matrix which is a clone of the first, shift it over and then averate the two matrices?

```
imIn = imread('Prueba.jpg');

nx = size(d,1);
ny = size(d,2);

% Create temporary matrices padded with nan
tmp1 = [nan(ny,2), d];
tmp2 = [d, nan(ny,2)];

imOut = tmp1;
imOut(:,:,2) = tmp2;

% use nanmean so the mean is just the value of the 1 column
imOut = nanmean(imOut,3);

out = imOut(2:end-1,:);
```

Comment: Yes, well I thought that also, but what I need to do is compute the average of every pixel with the left and right neighbor, row by row. So I appreciate your help but I'd love to make that code work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
imageIn = imread('Prueba.jpg');
imageIn = rgb2gray(imageIn);
imageOut = zeros(size(imageIn));

ny = size(imageIn, 1);
nx = size(imageIn, 2);

imshow(imageIn);

u = [];
v = [];

tic

for i = 1:ny
u = imageIn(i,:);
v = zeros(1, ny);
for k = 2:ny-1
v(k) = (uint32(u(k-1))+uint32(u(k))+uint32(u(k+1)))/3;
end
%Special cases first and last pixel
v(1) = (uint32(u(2))+uint32(u(1))+uint32(u(2)))/3;
v(ny) = (uint32(u(ny-1))+uint32(u(ny))+uint32(u(ny-1)))/3;
imageOut(i,:) = v;
end

toc
```

imshow(imageOut);

Comment: It seems to be the same code I put. Anyway I tried it but still `imageOut` is white

Comment: It sure looks like the same code. Hany Gharib, what did you change?